# Alphanumeric and Disable Options in Card Services in Gmail Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I want to do **validation** for **max length** and **alphanumeric** for **text input** in **card services**. I don't want the user to **enter** characters more than 1. and I want to add an **alphanumeric** feature to the **text input**. I want to **preventDefault** for **special** characters. I had done the code for **testing input value** was **valid** or **not valid**.

I tried the below code.

Can anyone guide me on the below two functionality?

1. **MaxLength** feature
2. **Alphanumeric** feature

**TextInput**

```
CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName(`Field150`)
  .setTitle("Field150")
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName("Field150"));
```

**InputHandler**

```
function Field150(e) {
  var inputFieldValue = e.formInput.Field150;
  console.log("inputFieldValue", inputFieldValue);
  var alphanumericRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

  if (alphanumericRegex.test(inputFieldValue)) {
    console.log("Valid alphanumeric input: " + inputFieldValue);
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
        .setText("Valid Value"))
      .build();
  } else {
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
        .setText("Invalid Value"))
      .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: For example for MaxLength I think this Regex would work `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}$/`, the other validation you want to apply is to not allow more than one specific character?

Comment: Yes I don't want to allow more than one character in the textinput